# Virtual many-to-many relationship

Tags: symfony, doctrine

let's imagine two distinct entities A and B is it possible to create a kind of virtual many-to-many relation.

I want A able to get all the B by id and B to get all A without using a join table.

I want to do this trick because my entities are not related. So, I can only access B from A using:

```
->join('App:entityB','b')
```

But this is not working using the normalizer.

I want my normalizer came from A to B and using a doctrine criteria in A to filter my B collection

```
/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function getEntitiesA()
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create();
    $criteria->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('foo', 'foo'));
    return $this->entitiesA->matching($criteria);
}
```

I have found resolve_target_entity on the symfony documentation can I use this for my purpose?
[resolve_target_entity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/resolve_target_entity.html)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand your issue - but you should be able to just call the getEntitiesForA() from the B entity and/or the reverse.

https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-bidirectional

Doctrine will create the join table you don't need an additional entity unless your associative table requires additional fields

Comment: Thanks but, I want to keep my entities unrelated even if doctrine take care of the join table

Comment: How do you mean unrelated? If you want bi-directional support each entity requires somewhat of a dependency on the other.

Comment: All my A can be associated with each one of my B. But I don't want to manage this relation with a table which associate both.

Comment: It seems quite bizarre to want 2 entities to know about each other but go out of your way to make them not related. If that's the case, then why do this in your entity class (or entity repository)? Just pull the records in your controller. They aren't related, so don't treat them as such. Or maybe explain to us what you are really trying to accomplish?

Comment: the resolve_target_entity look to me a good explanation. So I can "connect" my entity to other at runtime but I don't understand how to use it